# Perl read file and extract price

Tags: regex, perl

A file.txt file contains the string "hello the apple cost 10.99 today"

How can I extract the 10.99 only?

This is what I have so far:

```
open READFILE, ("<file.txt");
while (<READFILE>)
{   
    if ($a = $_ =~ m/\d\.\d/)
    {
        print "$a\n";
    }
}
```

However, my output shows 1 instead of 10.99. Can you please tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 1 you were getting was indicating that there was a match.  You need brackets to capture the match.

```
open READFILE, "<file.txt";
while (<READFILE>)
{
    if (m/([\d\.]+)/)
    {
        my $price = $1;
        print "price = $price\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this code, by brackets do you mean this inside the regex? /()/

Comment: Yes, what's in the () comes out as $1 in the next line

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this,

```
while (my $a = <DATA>) {
    if ($a =~ s/.*?(\d+\.\d+).*/$1/)
    {
        print "$a\n";
    }
}
```

- `s/regex/replacement/modifiers`

`s/.*?(\d+\.\d+).*/$1/` All characters are matched except the decimal point number. This number was captured by a capturing group. Replacing all the chars with the chars inside group index 1 will give only the decimal point number. That particular number was assigned to the variable `a`.

OR

```
while (my $a = <DATA>) {
    if ($a =~ m/.*?(\d+\.\d+).*/)
    {
        print "$1\n";
    }
}
```

The regex `.*?(\d+\.\d+).*` was matched against the input string and on successful match, decimal point number from the input string was captured. By printing the group index 1 will give you the stored decimal point number.

Comment: Thanks, this works great! Can you please explain the components of the regex one by one? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
 open READFILE, "file.txt";
 while (<READFILE>)
 {   
     if ($_ =~ /(\d+\.\d+)/)
     {
         print "$1\n";
     }
 }
```

You are good to go